# Low accuracy with Text Classification while trying to predict user's personality via Twitter

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, text-classification

I am working on a project to predict the personality of a user using his tweets.

For training, I have a large corpus of 350000 tweets of users who have already taken the personality test, each tweet being linked to a specific personality type.
There are 16 different personality types(1-16)

I have performed pre-processing on this tweets to remove stop words, stemming and POS tagging.

I have a large dictionary of 500 most frequent words that I will be using as my features for training.
After this, I have performed tfidf vectorization on each tweet using the predefined dictionary of 500 words to create a word vector for each tweet.

```
vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=mydict,min_df=1)
x=vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

Where corpus is a list of all the tweets.
I then combine this `x` and `y`(1-16 classes for each tweet) using:

```
result=np.append(x,y,axis=1)
X=pandas.DataFrame(result)
X.to_csv('vectorized500.csv')
```

I am using this (350000*500) dataframe as `X` and my 1-16 numbered personality types as my `Y` dataframe(350000*1) which is divided into training and testing equally using:

```
X=pd.read_csv('vectorized500.csv')
train = X.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=200)
test=X.drop(train.index)
y_train=train["501"] #501 is the column name where Y is in the csv file
y_test=test["501"]
xtrain=train.drop("501",axis=1)
xtest=test.drop("501",axis=1)
```

However, no matter what algorithm I run, I'm getting very poor results:

```
model=RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(xtrain,y_train)
pickle.dump(model, open('rf1000.sav', 'wb'))
print(model.score(xtest,y_test))
```

If i run `RandomForestClassifier`, i get 52% accuracy.

If I run Naive Bayes, Logistic Regression or Linear SVM, i get below 20% accuracy.

Is there any efficient way to run this kind of multiclass text classification or is there something I am doing wrong?
The accuracy is too low and I want to improve it.

Comment: How many examples from each class do you have?

Comment: Haven't counted that, but I'm sure atleast 15000 from each class. I'll compute it and get back to you.

Comment: Also, it would be better if you use some more examples for training rather than in testing. You mentioned that training and testing data points are equally divided. Try to use 80:20, 70:30 etc. (training:testing ratio). Furthermore, have you tried to tune the parameters for each algorithm?

Comment: `0. 56887 INFP
 1. 54607 INFJ
 2. 52511 INTJ
 3. 52028 ENFP
 4. 24294 INTP
 5. 19032 ENTJ
 6. 14284 ENFJ
 7. 12502 ISFJ
 8. 12268 ISTP
 9. 10713 ISTJ
10. 10523 ESFP
11. 8103 ESTP
12. 7436 ESFJ
13. 7016 ESTJ
14. 6725 ISFP`

Number of samples for each classification.

Comment: I have tried each and every combination. Even tried 67:33 ratio for training and testing, but the accuracy isnt deviating much

Comment: it predicts a number between 1 and 16, not 0 and 1. My target vector Y contains numbers between 1 and 16

Comment: the machine predicts based on this: `mbti={'INFP':1,'ISFJ':2,'INFJ':3,'INTJ':4,'ISTJ':5,'ISTP':6,'ISFP':7,'INTP':8,'ESTP':9,'ESFP':10,'ENTP':11,'ENFP':12,'ESTJ':13,'ESFJ':14,'ENFJ':15,'ENTJ':16}`

Comment: Since the four factors of Myers-Briggs are meant to be independent, why not train a classifier for each, and then give the combined result? I.e. train a classifier for Introvert vs Extravert, another for Intuitive vs Sensing, and so on.

Comment: why do you think 52% is low given that you have 16 classes?

Comment: I'd suggest finding the accuracy over each class separately to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Oh yes, will try doing each independently, thanks!

Comment: Did each class separately and now getting an average of 67% accuracy. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be the imbalanced dataset you are using.

```
0. 56887 INFP 1. 54607 INFJ 2. 52511 INTJ 3. 52028 ENFP 4. 24294 INTP 5. 19032 ENTJ 6. 14284 ENFJ 7. 12502 ISFJ 8. 12268 ISTP 9. 10713 ISTJ 10. 10523 ESFP 11. 8103 ESTP 12. 7436 ESFJ 13. 7016 ESTJ 14. 6725 ISFP
```

Imbalanced data, refers to a problem where the classes are not equally represented. There are many techniques that can be used for dealing with this phenomenon.

1. **Collect more data**

   Try if possible, to collect more data for the classes with few examples.
2. **Use other performance metrics**

   Accuracy is not a metric that can be used when your dataset is imbalanced. Imagine that you have two classes (`0` and `1`) where 99 examples belong to `class 0` and just 1 example to `class 1`. If you build a model that always assigns `class 0` to every testing point you will end up with 99% accuracy but obviously this is not what you want. Some useful metrics other than accuracy are the following:

   - Precision/Recall/F-score (Extracted from a Confusion Matrix)
   - ROC curves
3. **Undersampling**

   Try to discard examples from your most popular classes, so that all the classes have approximately the same amount of examples. Throwing data away might not be a good idea, so try to avoid undersampling.

Comment: 0. 4350 ENTJ
 1. 4132 INTJ
 2. 3810 INTP
 3. 3804 ENFJ
 4. 3709 ISTJ
 5. 3697 ISTP
 6. 3646 ISFJ
 7. 3608 INFP
 8. 3475 ESFJ
 9. 3472 ESTP
10. 3355 INFJ
11. 3299 ISFP
12. 3240 ESFP
13. 3238 ENFP
14. 3190 ESTJ
15. 1919 ENTP

new dataset which is balanced. No algorithm is giving me an accuracy better than 15%

Comment: Still imbalanced. Use exactly rhe same number of examples.